# Join two contracts into the same WSDL

Tags: .net, wcf, .net-4.0, workflow-foundation

Maybe it is science fiction, but i would like to know if it is possible to join a WF exposed with WCF and a WCF into the same WSDL. As you know a WF service (xaml) exposes a wsdl and a WCF (svc) exposes its own.

The background problem is that I do not want to differenciate long running process and short synchronous ones into different contracts because they belong to the same business logic.

Both of them are developed with framework 4.0.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you can do that.

What you can do is to use the Facade pattern, create a service that implements the interface of both your services. Expose this service externally and then call your individual services from it.